# Request permission dialog disappears immediately

Tags: android

In `MyApplication` at the launch of the app if the user Is not logged in I am starting login activity with flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`. In this login activity inside `onCreate()` I am requesting location permission. Permission dialog shows up but is automatically being dismissed before user has a chance to do anything. Why is that happening?
I ask for permission like this in the first lines of onCreate method:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mActivity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mActivity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                mActivity.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                        REQUEST_LOCATION_ACCESS_CODE);
            }
```

Comment: Do you have `<uses-permission>` elements for both of those permissions in the proper place in your manifest?

Comment: Also check this https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Yes, I do have permissions in manifest. Dialog is showing up but not for long...

Comment: Also when I ask for permission inside onCreate of my launch activity everything is ok

Comment: because you are not stopping the execution of further statements
just add return after requesting for permission like. if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                mActivity.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                        REQUEST_LOCATION_ACCESS_CODE);
           return;
            }
and execute call the methods which are required for the permission in onRequestPermissionsResult();

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have included

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

in your manifest

within your onCreate() check whether the permission is allowed or not like

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

  if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M &&!isPermissionAllowed()){
   ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Home.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);

   }else{
  //continue execution
  }
}

private boolean isPermissionAllowed(){
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && 
ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```